# git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date --root does not work

Tags: git, date, commit, rebase, author

I try to set the committer date of the latest commit to its author date. Usually this works with `git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date HEAD~1`. Unfortunately there is only one commit which means that I have to use `--root` instead of `HEAD~1` but `git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date --root` does not set the committer date to the author date for some reason. What can I do?

Comment: Try again your `git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date --root` with Git 2.19 (Q3 2018): that should now work. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51918234/6309).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### The bad news

Unfortunately `git rebase --root` uses the interactive rebase code (because the non-interactive code cannot "replay" the root commit), and `--committer-date-is-author-date` is actually a flag passed to `git am`, which implements the simple non-interactive cases.

#### The good news

What `git rebase` does, at a fundamental level, is *copy* some commits (with, usually, some sort of change made during the copying process), then point a branch name at the final such copied commit.  If there is just one commit you want to change-while-copying, you can use `git commit --amend` instead of `git rebase`.<sup>1</sup>  If there is only one commit in the entire repository, there can only be one commit that you need to change-while-copying, so this case will apply.

Instead of `--committer-date-is-author-date`, you will need to use the `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` variable to set the commit time stamp to some arbitrary value.  You can also use `--author` and/or `--date` to override the author name and/or time-stamp.  Hence:

```
t='2017-09-01 12:34:56'
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$t" git commit --amend --date="$t"
```

would set both time stamps to September 1st of 2017, at 12:34:56.  (I used a shell variable `t` here to avoid typing in the same time stamp twice.)

(Add `--no-edit` if you don't want to edit the commit message.  Remember that the new commit will use whatever is currently in the index!  If you have changed the index since extracting the HEAD commit, you may want to copy the `HEAD` commit to a temporary index first, and use that.)

---

<sup>1</sup>This assumes the change you want to make is, e.g., the commit message text or date or author or some such, rather than the commit's parent ID.  The definition of a root commit is one with no parent ID, and `git commit --amend` will continue to have no parent ID, which is what you want in this case.

Comment: FYI: `--amend --no-edit --date="..."` sounds like a usecase which often be shortened as `-C sha` where SHA points to a commit-id from where we want to take the author-date, author-email and commit-message.. Unfortunatelly, `-C` does not touch the 'committer' part, so the env-variable is still needed for that part

Answer (score 21):

#### TL;DR just give me a command line that works

`git filter-branch --env-filter 'export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE"'`

Comment: but this doesn't sign the commits. How can it be modified to add a GPG signature like when running `git commit --amend --no-edit -n -S`?

Comment: To re-sign all of them you can run `git filter-branch -f --commit-filter 'git commit-tree -S "$@";' -- --all` afterwards to re-sign all of them again.

Answer (score 7):

> But `git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date --root` does not set the committer date to the author date for some reason.

Actually, it might set it correctly, starting from Git 23.19 (Q3 2018)

The "`author-script`" file "`git rebase -i`" creates got broken when we started to move the command away from shell script, which is getting fixed now.

See [commit 5522bba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5522bbac2059283f7a91fa367fb1eb75faec2f3d), [commit 67f16e3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67f16e3d3fbd1eccda5d1cdb33d04cd087162057), [commit 0f16c09](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f16c09aaeabf0f543693a21535e670a2b808e9e), [commit ca3e182](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca3e1826a063ff7576a5e134f3b20b68196a1a5d) (31 Jul 2018) by [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1bc505b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1bc505b4768e9e48592bebfff35e18c5277412da), 17 Aug 2018)</sup>

> ### `sequencer`: fix "`rebase -i --root`" corrupting author header timestamp
>
> When "`git rebase -i --root`" creates a new root commit, it corrupts the
>   "`author`" header's timestamp by prepending a "`@`":
>
> ```
> author A U Thor <author@example.com> @1112912773 -0700
> ```
>
> The commit parser is very strict about the format of the "`author`" header, and does not allow a "`@`" in that position.
>
> The "`@`" comes from `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` in "`rebase-merge/author-script`",
>   signifying a Unix epoch-based timestamp, however, `read_author_ident()` incorrectly allows it to slip into the commit's "`author`" header, thus corrupting it.
>
> One possible fix would be simply to filter out the "`@`" when constructing
>   the "`author`" header timestamp, however, a more correct fix is to parse
>   the `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` date (via `parse_date()`) and format the parsed result
>   into the "`author`" header.
>   Since "`rebase-merge/author-script`" may be edited by the user, this approach has the extra benefit of catching other potential timestamp corruption due to hand-editing.
>
> We can do better than calling `parse_date()` ourselves and constructing
>   the "`author`" header manually, however, by instead taking advantage of
>   `fmt_ident()` which does this work for us.

Comment: `git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date --root` prints a: `fatal: cannot combine am options with either interactive or merge options` (git version 2.21.0.windows.1).  

It is expected though: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_incompatible_options

Comment: @40detectives Strange: it is incompatible with `--root` only when used in combination with `--onto`

Answer (score 0):

`git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date` works correctly with more recent git versions.
Note that on Ubuntu, it wasn't working with the `apt`-installed version and I had to install a more recent version following this https://itsfoss.com/install-git-ubuntu/ .