# How I can remove an already merged branch and preserve date

Tags: git

Suppose following git history with mainline A and already merged branch B.

```
                  b1     b2
             -----•------•---            B
            /                \
   •------•----•--------------•-------•  A
   a1     a2   a3             a4      a5
```

a4 is a merge commit w/ commit message merge "merge B into A.

Is it possible to to change the history into following.

```
                    b1'  b2'
   •-----•-----•-----•-----•-----•  A
   a1     a2   a3                a5
```

edit:
I don't want to change the commit date if possible.

Comment: Not without also rewriting `a5` into a new and different commit.

Comment: cherry pick b1, b2 at a3

Comment: `git rebase a2`

Comment: @Daniel1147 afaik cherry pick does not alter the commit whom picked from

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linearize git history, preserving all commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317019/linearize-git-history-preserving-all-commits)

Comment: @ElpieKay from which commit i should run the rebase?

Comment: `git rebase a2 A` is better. `git rebase a2` works if you are already on branch A. a3, b1, b2 and a5 will be rewritten and a4 will be flattened.

Comment: @RobinGreen my question differ in preserving the commit date as mentioned in the question

Comment: You can pass the `--committer-date-is-author-date` option when you run `git rebase` to achieve that.

Comment: @RobinGreen --committer-date-is-author-date does not work. the commits always get a the date of the rebase.

Comment: Yes, in some cases it does not work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395528/git-rebase-committer-date-is-author-date-root-does-not-work for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git cherry-pick` saves commit's date
1) go to commit a2 `git checkout a2`
2) create new branch C `git branch C`
3) go to new branch C `git checkout C`
4) fetch from A branch `git cherry-pick a3 b1 b2 a5`
5) go back to A `git checkout A`
6) remove permanently everything newer than commit a2 `git reset --hard a2`
7) fetch from branch C `git cherry-pick a3 b1 b2 a5`
8) And good to remove branch C, remove branch C `git branch -D C`

Comment: Thanks for the hint it don't solve the commit date problem for a5 and a3

Comment: It is not suitable for large repositories

Comment: What date in a5 and a3 do You expect? (Steps in my solution saves dates in same sequence as in your picture a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 a5)