# How can I sign git commits using GPG without changing the time of the commits in github?

Tags: git, github, gnupg

I didn't know about commit signing before, so I have a repo with a few thousand commits that I would like to sign.

[This question about signing previous commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41882919/is-there-a-way-to-gpg-sign-all-previous-commits) has several answers, but they change the date/time of the commit, which I would like to keep.

I understand that to sign all commits, I have to rewrite the commit history, so the commit hashes will change; that is fine.  But I hope there is a way to do it without changing the date/time of each commit-- after all, I just want to sign the commits and not make any other changes.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62202274/1209486) on a different question shows a way to update the date of all commits but it doesn't sign them.  And [this answer to the originally linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66254615/1209486) describes a way to preserve the commit date, which is what I want, but when I run the code

```
git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date -i --root
```

I get the error:

```
fatal: cannot combine am options with either interactive or merge options
```

This repository is on GitHub and has a simple structure with only two branches (main/dev) and a few thousand commits.  How can I automatically sign all the commits while preserving the commit dates/times?

Comment: Note that Git is working as intended. The commit time is supposed to track when the commit was made. The ***author time*** remains the same. Commit times will change, don't fight it. Use `git log --pretty=fuller` to see both. See [Difference between author and committer in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750808/difference-between-author-and-committer-in-git)

Comment: Or just sign your latest commit. It effectively signs off the history to that point in time.

Comment: You *could* write yourself some code (and/or steal the old filter-branch shell script code) to do this while setting `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` for each commit. I wouldn't bother though: as @jessehouwing says, signing the latest commit (or a tag for it) is effective. If you're in a super-high-security environment they might not accept this due to SHA-1 weakness, but if you're in that kind of environment they wouldn't look kindly on rewriting past commits either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/397149/can-you-gpg-sign-old-commits, but it is not recommended https://superuser.com/questions/1144817/is-it-a-good-idea-to-gpg-sign-old-git-commits